# Failed to start Corda node when connected to the Oracle database which is setup as production database

Tags: corda

My setup detail is as follows

- Corda 4.6 enterprise version
- Database : Oracle 12

I am doing production database setup by refering https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.6/node/operating/node-database-admin.html. I created 2 database schemas (Admin and restricted access) for each node. I updated node.conf database connection as per given in docuemntation. I also given permission to my_user to access my_admin_user

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<sid>"
    dataSource.user = my_user
    dataSource.password = "my_password"
}
database = {
    schema = my_admin_user
}
```

However getting below error while I start nodes

```
2021-06-09T16:36:16,400 ERROR databaseInitialisation DatabaseInitialisation(id="rK2VjTKa";status="error";error_code="1";message="**ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**  [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE my_user.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INTEGER NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR2(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR2(255), TAG VARCHAR2(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR2(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR2(255), LABELS VARCHAR2(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR2(10))]")

2021-06-09T16:36:16,413 ERROR net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupLogging **ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**
  [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE my_user.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INTEGER NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR2(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR2(255), TAG VARCHAR2(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR2(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR2(255), LABELS VARCHAR2(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR2(10))]
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem has been resolved after adding following entry under dataSourceProperties in node.conf

```
connectionInitSql="alter session set current_schema=my_admin_user"
```